# Make a length negative

Tags: macros, spacing, lengths

I was wondering if there is a way to have a `\negate` command which makes lengths negative. So you could do things like:

```
\newlength{\negativeabovecaptionskip}
\setlength\negativeabovecaptionskip{\negate{\abovecaptionskip}}

\the\abovecaptionskip %prints: 10pt
\the\negativeabovecaptionskip %prints: -10pt

%%But also:
\newlength{\negativeparskip}
\setlength\negativeparskip{\negate{\parskip}}

\the\parskip %prints: 15pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
\the\negativeparskip %prints: -15pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
%(notice that the the plus/minus values switched possitions)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do find your second requirement a bit curious. Why should the stretch and shrink part be exchange? Aren't you looking simply for the normal minus sign?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\negativeabovecaptionskip}
\setlength\negativeabovecaptionskip{-\abovecaptionskip}

\the\abovecaptionskip %prints: 10pt

\the\negativeabovecaptionskip %prints: -10pt

%%But also:
\newlength{\negativeparskip}
\setlength\negativeparskip{-\parskip}

\the\parskip %prints: 15pt plus 2pt minus 1pt

\the\negativeparskip %prints: -15pt plus 1pt minus 2pt

\end{document}
```

Comment: So did I, but decided to take on the challenge of the question as-written!

Comment: @Ulrike: You are right, just negating all tree numbers achieves the same result I wanted. I didn't know I could just use a minus sign like that. I think I tried it at some point and got an error, but I guess that was due to some bug in my code. It works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using e-TeX, you can do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\negate[1]{%
  -\dimexpr#1 plus\glueshrink #1 minus \gluestretch #1
}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\negativeabovecaptionskip}
\setlength\negativeabovecaptionskip{\negate{\abovecaptionskip}}

\the\abovecaptionskip %prints: 10pt

\the\negativeabovecaptionskip %prints: -10pt

%%But also:
\parskip 15pt plus 2pt minus 1pt

\newlength{\negativeparskip}
\setlength\negativeparskip{\negate{\parskip}}

\the\parskip %prints: 15pt plus 2pt minus 1pt

\the\negativeparskip %prints: -15pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
%(notice that the the plus/minus values switched positions)
\end{document}
```

making use of the fact that `\dimexpr` will turn a skip into a dimension, and that we can extract the stretch and shrink components.

Answer (score 3):

Switching the `plus` and `minus` parts has hardly a meaning, as Ulrike observes. If you don't insist in this,

```
\newcommand*{\negate}[1]{\glueexpr -2\glueexpr#1\relax+#1\relax}
```

Multiplying a glue parameter by a factor will annihilate the stretch and shrink component (and `\gluexpr` behaves like a glue parameter).

Note that prepending a simple minus sign to a glue parameter changes sign to each component without annihilating the stretch and shrink components, in contrast to prepending `-1`.

Comment: Why not just use `\dimexpr`?

Comment: With `\glueexpr` you can directly call `\negate{3pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}`, which you couldn't with `\dimexpr`. The argument of `\negate` might be generated as the expansion of some macro.